# Рисование графических примитивов в консоли на С++ с возможностью изменения размера и вращения

Tags: графика, c++

Здравствуйте, есть следующее задание:

Построить систему классов для описания плоских геометрических фигур: круг, квадрат, прямоугольник. Предусмотреть методы для создания объектов, перемещения на плоскости, изменения размеров и вращения на заданный угол. Написать программу, демонстрирующую работу с этими классами. Программа должна содержать меню, позволяющее осуществить проверку всех методов классов.

Так как я в этом деле ни в зуб ногой, то даже не знаю, с чего начать. С первой частью всё ясно - структура готова, а вот как рисовать в консоли, да ещё при этом так, чтобы можно было изменять размер рисунка и крутить его, это прямо-таки вопрос на миллион для меня.

Какие методы или библиотеки можно применить для решения задачи, или вообще можно использовать что-то кардинально другое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, рисование. Я бы предложил использовать что-то вроде графических функций [WinAPI](https://www.google.by/webhp?q=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20winapi#q=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+winapi) или [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). Это если рисование именно в консоли не является критически важным условием. В противном случае придётся использовать [graphics.h](http://valera.asf.ru/cpp/scpp/cppd_graphics.h.htm). В 2014 году использование данной библиотеки приравнивается к некрофилии, но если препод упёртый, то придётся.

Во-вторых, повороты и масштабирование фигур. Для этого используются [матрицы преобразований](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Для того, чтобы их использовать, координаты всех вершин ваших фигур должны быть представлены векторами. Эти вектора, умноженные на матрицы преобразований, превратятся в координаты повёрнутых/перемещённых/отмасштабированных фигур.

Comment: Какое такое graphics.h в консоли? В консоли может быть только ASCII-графика, в лучшем случае - ANSI :) Думаю, на самом деле просто не очень точная интерпретация задания.

Comment: ASCII графика скорее всего исключается, реализовать там повороты и масштабирование фигур - задача нетривиальная. Что именно имелось ввиду под фразой "рисование графических примитивов в консоли", конечно, не совсем ясно, но лично у меня сработал ассоциативный ряд консоль -> DOS -> graphics.h. Наверное, стоит подождать комментария автора вопроса.

Comment: М.б. творческое развитие "команды" `sl`?

Comment: С ASCII-графикой очень слабо вяжется требование "вращения на заданный угол". Можно, конечно, написать программу, осуществляющую растеризацию фигур в ASCII, но вероятность, что имелось ввиду именно это крайне мала. Если бы это было хоть как-то связано с ASCII-графикой, в задании хоть раз проскочило бы слово "ASCII" или "символ".

Comment: @fori1ton, естественно, это шутка.

--

Правда на некоторых алфавитно-цифровых терминалах (насколько помню DEC 320, например) можно было (в 80-е) программировать (по tty) матрицу (т.е. изображение символов) и т.о. здорово расширять возможности псевдографики.

--

Кстати, наверное подобное можно проделать и с PC-шной консолью.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку речь идёт о плоских фигурах, и, вероятно, простых, попробуем сделать всё примитивно. Ну, чисто для наглядности. И обойдёмся без окужности: перемещение её очевидно, а вращение и обсуждать нечего:-)

1) Перемещение. Совсем примитивно: чтобы переместить фигуру на [dX,dY], нужно координаты каждой вершины изменить на [dX,dY]. Всё.

2) Вращение. Будем считать, что координаты точки вращения [0,0]. Причём неважно, лежит эта точка внутри фигуры или вне её. Вот, собственно, и тоже всё: вспоминаем школьную тему "поворот точки относительно начала координат" и применяем этот подход (с заданным углом) ко всем вершинам.

Ну а дальше уже матрицы и прочая заумь :-)